# What's the color code of Bad and Good Highlights on Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I tried searching on goggle but couldn't figure out a good keyword to find it.
Anyone knows what color code I need to use on Excel VBA to get this?

Comment: For good: `Range("A1").Interior.Color=13561798` and for bad: `Range("B1").Interior.Color=13551615`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So macro recorder gives you this code:

```
Sub Macro2()
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.Style = "Good"
    Range("B1").Select
    Selection.Style = "Bad"
End Sub
```

Next step is to get color:

```
MsgBox Range("A1").Interior.Color ' returns 13561798
MsgBox Range("B1").Interior.Color ' returns 13551615
```

and finally, when you know color you can do this:

```
Range("A1:A10").Interior.Color = 13561798 ' for Good style
Range("B1:B10").Interior.Color = 13551615 ' for Bad style
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you want to use the Good or Bad styles you could simply use the style property of the range object i.e.

> Range("A1").Style = "Good"
>   Range("B1").Style = "Bad"